# How to straighten line endings in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, drawing, line

I'm new to Cocos2d and am trying out some of the basic drawing functions. When I draw a straight line with a high width (50 in this case), the ends of the line are not what I'd expect. What I'd like is for the line to be the same as it would be if I were using CoreGraphics, like this:

[image: A line drawn using core graphics]

however what I see in Cocos2d is this:

[image: A line drawn using Cocos2d]

The code I'm using to draw the line is in the layer's draw method:

```
-(void)draw
{
    glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
    glLineWidth(50);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(50, 50), ccp(250, 250));
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get cocos2d to draw a line with the same shape as the green image, rather than the red image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drawing it antialiased.

```
glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
glLineWidth(50);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
ccDrawLine(ccp(50, 50), ccp(250, 250));
```